# correct "Unformatted Partition" to NTFS

Tags: recovery-partition

I have 3 NTFS partitions with windows 7 installed.
I deleted both the first and second partition with a Windows 7 DVD in order to reinstall a fresh version of Windows.
After the installation, Windows has started and the third partition is recognized as "unknown". So I can't open it. Windows asks me to format it before using it.

This partition contains only 1 file of 540GB (TrueCrypt container).

I tried the following softwares but without success:
-PartitionGuru (I see "Unformatted(D:) NTFS 540.9 GB" but I can't nothing do with this software)
-testdisk (can't find the partition, even with a full search)
-photorec (it find the partition but it only restores *.gpg files that never existed on this partition)

An idea on how to recover my container?

Comment: Is it really a NTFS partition or an encrypted partition?

Comment: it's a standart NTFS partition...

Comment: With TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt (BTW, TrueCrypt shouldn't be used now that is no longer developed) can create both encrypted containers (files that can be stored anywhere) or encrypt an entire partition, hence my question. The "third partition is recognized as "unknown"" and the .gpg files found by photorec actually suggest the latter, but you say otherwise. If it's an encrypted partition you'd need to install VC to use it again. If it's as you say then somehow it became corrupt and in such cases not possible to recover.